# Using key while sorting values for just one column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say we have a df like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['y2','x3','z1','z1'],'B':['y2','x3','a2','z1']})

    A   B
0   y2  y2
1   x3  x3
2   z1  a2
3   z1  z1
```

if we wanted to sort the values on just the numbers in column `A`, we can do:

```
df.sort_values(by='A',key=lambda x: x.str[1])

    A   B
3   z1  z1
2   z1  a2
0   y2  y2
1   x3  x3
```

If we wanted to sort by both columns `A` and `B`, but have the key only apply to column `A`, is there a way to do that?

```
df.sort_values(by=['A','B'],key=lambda x: x.str[1])
```

Expected output:

```
    A   B
2   z1  a2
3   z1  z1
0   y2  y2
1   x3  x3
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to generate an extra column/separate Series with the output of your key function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort by `B`, then sort by `A` with a stable method:

```
(df.sort_values('B')
   .sort_values('A', key=lambda x: x.str[1], kind='mergesort')
)
```

Output:

```
    A   B
2  z1  a2
3  z1  z1
0  y2  y2
1  x3  x3
```